# JDBC SQLite journal file never commits

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, journal

I have a Java-written server which uses a connection using JDBC with SQLite which is set in auto commit mode. However all the queries end up generating a journal file and when the server restarts, the database looks never changed. Is there some general reason why this may happen? I know it would be helpful to provide some code, but I've been working on it for hours and I cannot even reproduce it with smaller amount of code...

Can anyone give a general idea of why a journal file is still there even when autocommit is set to true? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the reason. ResultSet has to be closed whenever we're done with it.

Comment: I know it's a really old question, but can you accept your answer? It helped me.